# Phpunit test in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is there any way I can run a test over current file?

I have setup the phpunit for the entire library I created, but sometimes I need to run the thes only from the current file.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking?

Comment: I did , but it would not include the phpunit.xml file. Upgrading to the last version (EAP 8) worked great.

Comment: *"I did , but it would not include the phpunit.xml file"* Have you configured defaults (under `Defaults` branch)? Have you provided default path to your phpunit.xml?

Comment: Yes. I did, but in PHPStorm 7, when running a tested over a single File, that file was not completed by default. In PHPSTORM 8 it worked. It's possible that I had bad configuration on general settings

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to the last version (8, EAP) and everythink works great by choosing "Run 'Filename' with Coverage"